# Using UITapGestureRecognizer inside a UIPageViewControllerDataSource not working

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, uipageviewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have been trying to add a UITapGestureRecognizer in order to make it possible to change views using buttons inside my UIPageViewControllerDataSource.

I have added the subclasses

```
@interface OverallViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;
```

Page navigation works fine for me but when trying the following UITapGestureRecognizer inside viewDidLoad I get nothing

```
UIView *topbar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 52)];
    topbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(245/255.0) alpha:1];
    left = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-profile-sm.png"]];
    left.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 25, 25);
    //End add top nav


    [topbar addSubview:left];
    [self.view addSubview:topbar];

    //Add top navigation gestures
    UITapGestureRecognizer *profiletap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(profileButtonTap)];
    profiletap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    profiletap.delegate = self;

    [left addGestureRecognizer:profiletap];
```

No response here

```
-(void) profileButtonTap {
NSLog(@"Profile button tapped");
}
```

And nothing when I try overriding gestureRecognizer

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    NSLog(@"Touch: %f,%f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
        if (touchPoint.y < 52) {
            return NO; // ignore the touch
        }

    return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

When I say that I get nothing I mean that nothing is logged, the methods do not seem to be called and I am unsure how I can solve or debug this further. Thanks for any help, ideas and suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried setting `left.userInteractionEnabled = YES`?

Comment: such a simple mistake that I should never have missed and I spent hours looking for different solutions... Thanks for the help :)